# FMDB : Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: linker, command, fmdb

I try to use FMDB Database but I've got an error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FMDatabase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've added the src directory except : fmdb.m, libsqlite3.0.dylib to my librairies
and I've imported "FMDatabase.h" in my Appdelegate.h

Comment: If I Delete FMDB files and drag again the directory it works.

Comment: Can you tell me why it resolves the problem ?

Answer (score 11):

This issue is caused by FMDB not being able to find the libsqlite3.0.dylib library. Import that into your project clicking on your project at the top of the Project Navigator, clicking on the "Build Phases" tab, and clicking on the plus button to add it under the  "Link Binary With Libraries" section.

Answer (score 0):

I could only guess, but i think that you have missed "Add to targets" checkbox while adding files to project. Also you could check this checkbox (if you forget to do it while importing) in the file inspector's target membership's block.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by FMDB not being able to find the **liFMDB-IOS.a** library. Import that into your project clicking on your project at the top of the Project Navigator, clicking on the "Build Phases" tab, and clicking on the plus button to add it under the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.